# When creating compute node, '_allocate_network_async' threw Error 'Permession dennied' in amqpdriver.py

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I'm writing a nova driver. The driver just wraps some REST api of our service.

When creating a compute node, a "Permission denied" error was thrown in 
amqpdriver.py:341.

I've debugged all afternoon but no luck.
I think the error may caused by some permission setting about the messaging server. And I think it is nothing todo with our driver.
Anyone can help?

log:

```
    2015-10-12 23:08:25.447 4654 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connecting to AMQP server on os-svr:5672
    2015-10-12 23:08:25.458 4654 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on os-svr:5672
    2015-10-12 23:08:25.671 4654 INFO nova.virt.bluecube.driver [req-503143f9-ff96-4779-806a-4cb6c5f6b0e9 60e5627c9c8f4eea9e8af0dbc3dedfb4 9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967 - - -] ..........
    2015-10-12 23:08:25.671 4654 INFO nova.virt.bluecube.driver [req-503143f9-ff96-4779-806a-4cb6c5f6b0e9 60e5627c9c8f4eea9e8af0dbc3dedfb4 9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967 - - -] {u'status': u'active', u'deleted': False, u'container_format': u'bare', u'min_ram': 0, u'updated_at': u'2015-10-12T10:50:41.000000', u'min_disk': 0, u'owner': u'9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967', u'is_public': True, u'deleted_at': None, u'properties': {}, u'size': 13287936, u'name': u'cirros-0.3.4-x86_64', u'checksum': u'ee1eca47dc88f4879d8a229cc70a07c6', u'created_at': u'2015-10-12T10:50:41.000000', u'disk_format': u'qcow2', u'id': u'a67d9dd0-c69f-4083-b92b-8c5d8be5887a'}
    2015-10-12 23:08:25.672 4654 INFO nova.virt.bluecube.vmops [req-503143f9-ff96-4779-806a-4cb6c5f6b0e9 60e5627c9c8f4eea9e8af0dbc3dedfb4 9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967 - - -] [instance: 255ce379-7a74-4d5f-8382-aa3b507bb9fc] Spawning new instance
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager [-] Instance failed network setup after 1 attempt(s)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1783, in _allocate_network_async
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     dhcp_options=dhcp_options)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/api.py", line 49, in wrapped
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return func(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/base_api.py", line 64, in wrapper
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     res = f(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/api.py", line 281, in allocate_for_instance
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     nw_info = self.network_rpcapi.allocate_for_instance(context, **args)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/rpcapi.py", line 152, in allocate_for_instance
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     macs=jsonutils.to_primitive(macs))
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 156, in call
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     retry=self.retry)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 90, in _send
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 350, in send
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     retry=retry)
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 341, in _send
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     raise result
    2015-10-12 23:08:26.551 4654 ERROR nova.compute.manager     OSError: [Errno 13] Permission deined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root error is in nova-network.log.

According to the log, some file action raise permission error.

I'm focus on nova-compute so just skip the operation without any fix.
In nova.conf, add the option, and most of network operation can be skipped.

```
    fake_network=True
```

Here are errors in nova-compute.log

```
2015-10-13 17:13:41.150 814 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-1ab6c333-c5ab-4906-94aa-820dc2de1d14 60e5627c9c8f4eea9e8af0dbc3dedfb4 9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967 - - -] Exception during message handling:    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networks'
2015-10-13 17:13:41.150 814 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networks'
2015-10-13 17:13:41.153 814 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-1ab6c333-c5ab-4906-94aa-820dc2de1d14 60e5627c9c8f4eea9e8af0dbc3dedfb4 9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967 - - -] Returning exception [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networks' to caller
2015-10-13 17:13:41.153 814 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.common [req-1ab6c333-c5ab-4906-94aa-820dc2de1d14 60e5627c9c8f4eea9e8af0dbc3dedfb4 9700d79ee83b4522b6bc7edfb135f967 - - -] ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 142, in _dispatch_and_reply\n    executor_callback))\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 186, in _dispatch\n    executor_callback)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 130, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/floating_ips.py", line 113, in allocate_for_instance\n    **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/manager.py", line 500, in allocate_for_instance\n    requested_networks=requested_networks)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/manager.py", line 194, in _allocate_fixed_ips\n    vpn=vpn, address=address)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/manager.py", line 971, in allocate_fixed_ip\n    \'be required.\'), exc_info=True)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 195, in __exit__\n    six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/manager.py", line 947, in allocate_fixed_ip\n    self._setup_network_on_host(context, network)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/manager.py", line 1855, in _setup_network_on_host\n    self.driver.update_dhcp(elevated, dev, network)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/linux_net.py", line 1042, in update_dhcp\n    conffile = _dhcp_file(dev, \'conf\')\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/network/linux_net.py", line 1276, in _dhcp_file\n    fileutils.ensure_tree(CONF.networks_path)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/openstack/common/fileutils.py", line 38, in ensure_tree\n    os.makedirs(path, mode)\n', '  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs\n    mkdir(name, mode)\n', "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networks'\n"]
```